# What does [++]*+ stand for in regexp

Tags: java, android, regex, libphonenumber

I'm using [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) and I try to check some phone numbers if they are valid with regexp pattern VALID_PHONE_NUMBER which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/trunk/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.java)  and it looks like this

```
private static final String VALID_PHONE_NUMBER =
      DIGITS + "{" + MIN_LENGTH_FOR_NSN + "}" + "|" +
      "[" + PLUS_CHARS + "]*+(?:[" + VALID_PUNCTUATION + STAR_SIGN + HASH_SIGN +"]*" + DIGITS + "){3,}[" +
      VALID_PUNCTUATION + STAR_SIGN + HASH_SIGN + VALID_ALPHA + DIGITS + "]*";
```

On my Android phone this expression is compiled to following

```
\p{Nd}{1}|[++]*+(?:[-x--?-?--/  ­?? ()()[].\[\]/~?~~*#]*\p{Nd}){3,}[-x--?-?--/  ­?? ()()[].\[\]/~?~~*#DEFGABCLMNOHIJKUTWVQPSRYXZdefgabclmnohijkutwvqpsryxz\p{Nd}]*
```

What does it mean `[++]*+`

Does it mean "plus-or-plus zero-or-more-times and then plus?

Does it make any sense to have two pluses next to each other?

Comment: That isn't a valid regex.

Comment: I checked the regex at the link you gave and there is no `[++]*+` but there is `[+]*+` which is a possessive quantifier since you are using Java.

Comment: well I see static final String PLUS_CHARS = "+\uFF0B"; and I belive that it's ++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[++]` matches a `+` or a `+`

`*+` matches the `[++]` zero or more times, possessively

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Answer (score 2):

The rightmost `+` is fairly new.  As others have said, `[++]` means "find a single `+`".  with the `*` quantifier: `[++]*` means "zero or more plus signs".

The extra rightmost `+` in `[++]*+` is not supported by all Regular Expression engines, but means "do not do any backtracking", i.e. do a "maximum match".  Contrast with `?`, which does a minimum match.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485958/understanding-possessive-quantifiers-java-regex)

Answer (score 2):

`+` within character class is treated as a literal..It should be `[+]*+`

`*+` is [Possessive Quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)..It doesn't backtrack..

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No

A character class (`[...]`) ignores duplicate characters.
Therefore, `[++]` is equivalent to `\+`.

Comment: I think the final `+` is a possessive quantifier.

Comment: In most popular regex implemetations, the `+` in `*+` denotes `*` is possessive: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Answer (score 0):

The second `+` is redundant both inside and outside the character class.

Within the character class `[++]` it's just ignored. Outside the character class it acts as a quantifier (one or more) <s>but isn't valid because</s> except when preceded with another quantifier like `*` here (for zero or more) as then it denotes *possessiveness*.

More info at **[Possessive Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)**

> You can make a quantifier possessive by placing an extra + after it. E.g. * is greedy, *? is lazy, and *+ is possessive. ++, ?+ and {n,m}+ are all possessive as well.

Comment: I think the final `+` is a possessive quantifier.