# clear understanding on possesive quantifiers

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

i have read so many questions and answers on possessive quantifiers in java in this website and java tutorials but **men, am still confused!! am not understanding!!** for example lets say

```
 my regex is .*+foo
 my input string is mdfoo
```

according to my understanding,

```
.(dot) means there are other characters before foo

*(star) means if foo should be writen in a string form if found by regex

+foo means that a string should end with foo for it to match
```

and in my input string,it ends with foo. but when i receive a statement that there was no match when i run my program! how is this happening and what should i do still using the (+) quantifier to receive a match ?. thanks in advance

Comment: Besides the one I already mentioned, here are more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117467/can-someone-explain-possessive-quantifiers-to-me-regular-expressions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485958/understanding-possessive-quantifiers-java-regex and even [more](https://www.google.com/search?q=possessive+quantifiers+stackoverflow)...

Comment: @Bart Kiers okey, i got it sir. i will read all of them

Answer (score 0):

The possessive quantifier implies that no backtracking is done.

What happens when you try to match `mdfoo` against `.*+foo`:

1. The first part of the pattern (i.e. `.*+`) matches the whole string `mdfoo`
2. But the second part of the pattern (i.e. `foo`) is not found after the first match
3. Since there is no backtracking, the attempt immediately fails

These possessive quantifiers are quite clearly explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Comment: @spOOm thanks, your answer is straight to the point. so it seems like i cant use possessive to help a user search for something? its like possessive have no great importance?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene Well, the question actually is: why do you think you need a possessive quantifier?

Comment: @spOOm i think i need possessive to speed up my regex and help my regex fail faster.

Comment: @spOOm thats what i know about benefits of possesive. is there any great benefit you can tell me?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization `;)`

Comment: @spOOm men, you knocked me in ma head. i got the message.

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of quantifiers:

- the "regular" quantifiers (*, +, ?) also called "greedy" quantifiers;
- the "lazy", quantifiers (*?, +?, ??);
- the "possessive" quantifiers (*+, ++, ?+).

For instance, take this input:

```
The answer is 42
```

Now, take this regex:

```
.*(\d+)
```

The question is, what will be captured by `(\d+)` according to which version of `*` you use in `.*`:

- if `*`, what will be captured is `2`;
- if `*?`, what will be captured is `42`;
- if `*+`, the regex *does not match*.

Why:

- the greedy quantifier swallows everything it can; however, it retains, on its way, the positions where it has matched; when having swallowed the full text, there is still `\d+` to match; it will reluctantly backtrack until `\d+` is satisfied, and `\d+` is satisfied with `2`;
- the lazy quantifier tries and queries the following regex token: "if \d+ does not match then I swallow the next character"; when encountering `4` it lets `\d+` do its job, therefore `42` is captured;
- the possessive quantifier is possessive; it works like the greedy quantifier *except that it does not retain any positions*; therefore, when reaching the end, the regex engine asks "OK, can you give back?", `.*+` says "No...", therefore no match.